# The right column on the GetBootstrap website, how is it created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the GetBootstrap website ( http://www.getbootstrap.com ), virtually every page underneath the header is made up of two columns; one on the left where the information/content is located and one on the right where a menu expands as you scroll down the page. How is that menu that expands created?

For example, on the Components page of GetBootstrap, if you click on the Nav (in the right column), it expands, and the content (left column) immediately scrolls to that section. If you later click within the menu of Nav, the left column also instantly scrolls to that section, while the right column remains in that same expanded state.

Furthermore, if all you did was scroll down to view the content of the left column, the menu on the right column expands as you reach the headings within it.

How is this action created?

Comment: Read up on  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment cause my reputation isnt high enough, So I guess I post an answer, but its not a complete answer - Sorry!

It seems they are using a combination of [ScollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) and [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Comment: Thank you for telling me what it is! At least now I know what it is called.